# Entering '+', '-' chars into char arrays

Tags: c

I'm new to C and coding in general, and while learning about Arrays I came across this issue that I'm really confused about.

With the following code:

```
int main (void)
{
    char op[100]; 
    int nums[100][3];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        scanf("%c", &op[i]);
        scanf ("%i %i", &nums[i][0], &nums[i][1]);
        printf ("%c %i %i currently at row: %i \n", op[i], nums[i][0], nums[i][1], i);
    }
}
```

I'm just trying to store a char in a char array and 2 numbers in the nums[100][3] array, but when I run the code and enter:

**+ 2 2**, for the 1st time it works, producing an output of **+ 2 2 currently at row: 0** .

But for some reason, when I enter

**+ 2 2** the 2nd time it throws out a really wonky output:  **0 298786944 currently at row: 1**

and I am really really confused over this.

Thanks in advance  guys and hope to hear from you soon

Comment: `'\n'` is a character too that is read by `scanf("%c", &op[i]);`  `scanf ("%i %i", &nums[i][0], &nums[i][1]);` did not check the return value of `scanf()`.  That is important to know how successful the function was.

Comment: `scanf("%c"` --> `scanf(" %c"`,  `scanf("%i %i"` --> `scanf("%d %d"`

Comment: Change that to `scanf("%c %i %i", op + i, nums[i], nums[i] + 1);`. Just note that I chnged to pointers because it's cleaner that way, your version isn't wrong. Just keep in mind, the way you want to do this, athere should be one scanf. Or do what M.M just said